# Create a little python applet in a linux task bar

Tags: python, linux, gtk, pygtk, statusbar

I would like to create for my linux task bar a little applet in python, which simply display an icon that could change of color, and when we click on it, which show a simple information menu. 
But I have no idea about the resources I could use to perform it.

I started with gtk and in particular I found the `gtk.status_icon_new_from_file` to display an svg icon. But I can't dynamically change the icon's color through the svg. I have to modify the colors in my file, and then to reload it. Is there a way to give directly the data of the icon rather than the name of it ?

Besides, I don't know where to continue then to code my menu. Any idea ?

Finally, is it possible to some text above an icon ?

**Edit :** I would like to have solution about a generic taskbar, since I'm using tint2 (with openbox) under archlinux. So I need solutions compatible with the freedesktop recommendations and not specific to Gnome or Ubuntu. Maybe solutions with a xfce4 desktop.

Comment: We'd need to first know which distro and desktop you're running. There's no such thing like "linux task bar", because there's a variety of softwares providing this feature. You're trying to use GTK, is your Desktop Environment GNOME 2 ? GNOME 3 ? Xfce ? Unity ?

Comment: I'm not really using a desktop environment but openbox with tint2 as taskbar.

Comment: While there's no such thing as a "Linux task bar", there are protocols followed by modern desktop environments that implement a form of system tray. The most well-known one is [specified by freedesktop.org](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/systemtray-spec/), and is used by applications such as Skype to implement system tray functionality without having separate code for Gnome 2/3, KDE, xfce, Unity, etc. The OP needs to find a library that implements freedesktop system tray spec and has Python bindings.

Answer (score 0):

Status icon is most generic solution, but legacy.

Appindicator was designed for ubuntu to easy keep icon and menu in taskbar.

There is examples in several languages
http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/technologies/application-indicators/

What is your Desktop Shell? Each shell has a better way to keep applet on taskbar. Some of these solutions has compatibility with other shells (appindicator has support in KDE, Gnome2, Gnome Shell and maybe others).

Comment: AppIndicator is specific to Ubuntu, and the guy hasn't even told you which distro/desktop he runs.

Comment: I'm not under Ubuntu, but under archlinux. So I can't use that. I saw this framework which would be very interesting, but I can't use it.

Comment: it fallback to tray icon if no appindicator support.

Comment: Then he'd better directly code for the GtkStatusIcon API, as he won't be able to test on Ubuntu anyway.